# Save output command in a variable and write for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script. I list my jpg files inside nested subdirectories with the following command line:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg"
```

How can I save the output of this command inside a variable and write a for loop for that? (I want to do some processing steps for each jpg file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than storing in a variable, use this :

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec command {} \;
```

Even, if you want, command can be a full bloated shell script.

A demo is better than an explanation, no ? Copy paste the whole lines in a terminal :

```
cat<<'EOF' >/tmp/test
#!/bin/bash

echo "I play with $1 and I can replay with $1, even 3 times: $1"
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/test
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec /tmp/test {} \;
```

### Edit: new demo (from new questions from comments)

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | head -n 10 | xargs -n1 command
```

(this another solution doesn't take care of filenames with newlines or spaces)

This one take care :

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

count=0

for file in **/*.jpg; do
    if ((++count < 10)); then
        echo "process file $file number $count"
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Then, how can I select each jpg file separately without a for loop over the list of jpg files? Also, Can I write multiple commands inside the command {}?

Comment: Added simple for loop, better suitable for your needs

Comment: Use just the latest solution alone

Comment: I can not because I have to use the find command to get list of jpg images in nested subdirectories and do processing on the middle jpg images which have better quality.

Comment: He, I give you all what you need (3 solutions), time to test and read doc now ;)

Comment: Please clean up useless comments

Comment: They have been very helpful. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to store output containing multiple files into a variable/array and then post-process it later. You can just do those actions on the files on-the-run.

Assuming you have `bash` shell available, you could write a small script as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ bash shell needed over any POSIX shell because
#                   of the need to use process-substitution <()

while IFS= read -r -d '' image; do
    printf '%s\n' "$image"
    # Your other actions can be done here
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0)
```

The `-print0` option writes filenames with a null byte terminator, which is then subsequently read using the `read` command. This will ensure the file names containing special characters are handled without choking on them.